# Make button NOT post

Tags: asp.net, html, post, button

The ultimate goal is to have a div "animate" down when the button is clipped and the "top" is less than 0.  I wanted to use a button (for the style) but when I do so, it seems to be posting.  Here's my button:

```
<button id="expcoll" class="expcoll" onclick="expcoll();" runat="server">↓</button>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
function expcoll() {
    var dFilter = document.getElementById("dFilter");
    var expcoll = document.getElementById("MainContent_expcoll");
    if (dFilter.offsetTop == 0) {
        $("#dFilter").css({ 'top': -200 });
        expcoll.innerHTML = "↓";
    }
    else {
        $("#dFilter").css({ 'top': 0 });
        expcoll.innerHTML = "↑";
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better way or a way to make it to where the button does not post?  If you're curious as to why I'm trying to use a button, I tried doing mouseenter and mouseleave, but because a few of the textboxes open up jQuery calendars, whenever I do that, the div collapses (yet the calendar stays).  I then did a "click" function on the div, but if I clicked in the textboxes, it would close (but the calendar stays).  Please let me know if you need anymore information.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is it `runat="server"`, if you don't want to postback?

Comment: I didn't even think of that.  Let me try that.

Comment: This syntax is odd. What kind of html is that?

Comment: "POST"? you mean post a form?, do you have anymore code there?

Comment: The button is inside a form, because there are other buttons that POST, but I don't want this one to post.  As far as the syntax, I'm not sure what you mean why it's odd.  And Oded, when I took out runat="server" it wouldn't let me use onclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client-side click event needs to return false to abort the postback. Try adding the following:

```
<button id="expcoll" class="expcoll" onclick="expcoll();return false;" runat="server">↓</button>
```

If you can, you should use the ASP.NET button control:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="expcoll();return false;" ...>
```

**EDIT**

It might be neater if you just returned false at the end of the function (thanks @Jon Hanna):

```
function expcoll() { 
    var dFilter = document.getElementById("dFilter"); 
    var expcoll = document.getElementById("MainContent_expcoll"); 
    if (dFilter.offsetTop == 0) { 
        $("#dFilter").css({ 'top': -200 }); 
        expcoll.innerHTML = "↓"; 
    } 
    else { 
        $("#dFilter").css({ 'top': 0 }); 
        expcoll.innerHTML = "↑"; 
    } 
    return false;
} 

<button id="expcoll" class="expcoll" onclick="return expcoll();" runat="server">↓</button>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much.  I had put my "return false;" inside of the function rather than after it.

Comment: If you'd the `return false` in the function, then you could also have used `onclick="return expcoll();"`. In this case it'd be pretty much the same as @JamesJohnson's answer, but in other cases it would let the function decide whether to allow the submission or not, which can be useful a lot of the time.

Comment: @JonHanna: Yes, you're right. You could just return false at the end of the function if you wanted to.

Comment: Little difference in this case though, just since that seemed to be the lines the OP was thinking along.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a client side button, don't set `runat="server"`.

By the way giving the same name to a function and an element ID is not a good idea - the javascript engine might not figure out that you are trying to call the function and instead try to call the element...

Comment: If I do that, it won't let me use onclick.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity - What do you mean "it won't let me"? Red squiggles? If so, ignore them and _try_ it.

Comment: This might just be Visual Studio, but it says: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".  But if I put the runat="server" back in there, it works-ish (just refreshes the page).

Comment: As far as the ID, it actually get changed at runtime to MainContent_expcoll.  I know I should change it regardless, this is just something I'm messing with right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this answer, but it's worth a shot. I think you can just put a `return false;` at the end of your javascript onClick() method and it will prevent the postback.

Edit: also you might try onClientClick() event

Comment: The onClientClick allowed me to work without the runat="server" but it still "refreshed" the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to call `expcoll()` you need to call it from `OnClientClick` as this is the client-side click event. In other words, your markup should look like this:

```
<asp:button id="expcoll" Text="↓" class="expcoll" onClientclick="expcoll();" OnClick ="EventHandlerForClickOnServerSide" runat="server"></asp:button>
```

**EDIT**

Reading more carefully, It seems that you don't want a server control. Do this instead:

```
<input id="expcoll" class="expcoll" type="button" onclick="expcoll();">↓</input>
```